# Can I use Leaflet as an es6 module? Plugins too?

Tags: javascript, module, leaflet, gis

Looking at the Leaflet docs, I don't see how to import Leaflet as an es6 module. And more importantly, all the Leaflet plugins as well.

Skypack converts Leaflet to modules:

```
import * as leaflet from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/leaflet'
```

But I'm not sure how safe this approach would be. I'd prefer unpkg, but this:

```
https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1?module
```

.. produces:

```
Package leaflet@1.7.1 does not contain an ES module
```

So basically will using Leaflet in a "modern" repo run into problems with modules?

Comment: The doc/download page https://leafletjs.com/download.html says it should work with npm install leaflet and then import from dist folder

Comment: Whats wrong with `import L from 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet'`?

Comment: Also, as far as plugins go, there's no general rule.  While most plugins do have a package hosted on npm, not all of them do, and you have to read each plugin's docs to see how they recommend using their code

Comment: Seth: https://unpkg.com/leaflet simply gives me a UMD, not a module. And as I said, adding "?module" fails to find one.

Comment: Seth: the import you suggested yields: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'L' of undefined. Adding the ?module query string yields a 404.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaflet can be used as a module by importing it manually:

```js
import * as leaflet from "https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.esm.js";
```

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a minified module build so uncompressed download size will be higher (422kB vs 147kB for `leaflet@1.9.3`, for example).